# How to create a new tenant using only the main mysql user in Laravel "hyn/multi-tenant" package

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, multi-tenant

In Laravel "hyn/multi-tenant" by default, when a new tenant is created, the package creates a new mysql user for tenant database.

How to create a new tenant using only the main mysql user without creating a new mysql user?

Comment: you can set the variable in the config file to false: `'auto-create-tenant-database-user' => false `